# retryWhen() doesn't call what's inside Observable.just()

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, kotlin, observable

I have a test which in which I check retry mechanism for token authorisation. Inside that test I return null as token in the beginning and then I return a valid token, like this:

```
whenever(accountManager.getToken())
            .thenReturn(null)
            .thenReturn("some_token")
```

Then I have an Observable:

```
    return Observable.just(accountManager.getToken())
            ...
            .retryWhen { retryOnAuthExceptionWithBackoff(it) }
```

It should get the token, send it somewhere, wait for response and then it the response is wrong, retry the whole process again until it succeeds.

The problem is that when `retryWhen()` kicks in, the source observable is not called again, just its initial value is returned immediately.

On the other hand, this **does** work:

```
    return Observable.just(null)
            .map{ accountManager.getToken() }
            ...
            .retryWhen { retryOnAuthExceptionWithBackoff(it) }
```

Is it by design or is it a bug? If it's by design, what would be an elegant way to write this, because `Observable.just(null)` looks just ugly.

Comment: Let me rearrange your code:

Object x = accountManager.getToken();
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(x); // <-- should this print a non-null value?

Observable.just(x).subscribe(System.out::println);

Comment: No, in your example you only invoked `getToken()` once. If you wrote `Object x = accountManager.getToken();` `Object y = accountManager.getToken();` then in my example `y` would not be null. The point is that upon the second read from `accountManager.getToken()` it already has the token. If that function was resolved twice inside `Observable.just`, it would return different values (as it does in my second example).

Comment: Do you think just() invokes your getToken function? Wrong. Just() takes a constant value reference and keeps handing out the **same** reference to subscribers.

Comment: That's what I figured. But thanks for ensuring me with that. Now, do you know some more elegant solution to this problem than mapping null?

Comment: `Observable.fromCallable(() -> accountManager.getToken())`.

Comment: Damn, I feel so stupid now... Thanks. Can you write answer so that I can accept that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `just()` takes a constant value reference and keeps handing out the same reference to subscribers.

What you need is `fromCallable`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> accountManager.getToken())
...
```

Whenever a new subscriber (such as a retry) comes in, the lambda is executed again.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! Since `retryWhen` and `repeatWhen` doesn't call the function again to get a new Observable and instead they resubscribe to previous observable, I wasn't sure how to return a different value from a re-subscription until now.  This is especially useful if you want to test "failure then success" scenario because you can't emit item after an error.